# Microsoft ODBC Driver Manager Datasource name not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, informix

I have this code that connects to informix server using nodejs.

```
var ibmdb = require("ifxnjs");
var ConnectionString = "SERVER=ids;DATABASE=jinx_live;HOST=128.0.8.123;SERVICE=ids_tcp;UID=informix;PWD=boin*2017;";
ibmdb.open(ConnectionString, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("an error occurred:> "+err);
        return;
    }
    connection.query("select 1 from mytab1", function (err1, rows) {
        if (err1) console.log(err1);
        else console.log(rows);
        connection.close(function(err2) { 
            if(err2) console.log(err2);
        });
    });
});
```

But the moment I run this java script file I get the error message below on the console log.

> an error occurred:> Error: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data
>   source name not found and no default driver specified

Whats am I not doing right. Am new to informix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have installed **Informix Client SDK 4.10 FC2 or above** and setup correctly. Also the node.js libraries that you are using is also 64bit and it node.js v8.x.

Comment: Do I have to purchase this SDK? because IBM site keeps telling me My order has an error that I need an assistance contract support?, I cant download the SDK am stuck..

Comment: yeah thanks I had to get a license with IBM to get the SDK and do many other configurations inorder for it to work.